# How maintain java application scope variables after session expire

Tags: java, session, servlets, web-applications

i am using servlet context to maintain session variables.If user log out i will remove the variable from application scope and its works file. I have problem when session was not closed properly (example network failure and log out was not proper) the variable still remain in application scope.
  How to handle such a situation? How can to detect if browser disconnect from server so that it can be removed from application scope?

Comment: can you add a session timeout?

Comment: the browser does not (necessarily) remain connected to the server between requests- you never know if the user is still there reading the web page, or if the user has left your "application". The only way to reliably handle this in all cases is using session timeouts. (Alternatives are plenty but don't always work, using Javascript, websockets, etc.)

Comment: i already configured session timeout, But how can i remove  variable from application scope corresponding to that session. i am not able to track session timeout .